# PHP - problem with urls and charsets

Tags: php, url, character-encoding

When my URL contains a get with `"בלה בלה"`
, the url stays in hebrew and when I do `echo $_GET['hebrew']`, it outputs it in hebrew, great. However, when it contains `"São Paulo"`, it starts going nuts, the URL changes to `"S%E3o%20Paulo"` and the output is `"S�o Paulo"`.

This gets me extremely frustrated, can anyone of you guys help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only safe thing to do is to create URL's that have %xx for the UTF-8, not non-ASCII characters. If you do otherwise, your mileage will vary all over the place. The process of turning a byte sequence into one with %xx escapes is called URL-encoding. You'll need a PHP expert to tell you how to do that there.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP I can't help you with. What I know is what's safe to send around on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your URLs using `urlencode`, which a browser usually does for you, but as @bmargulies mentions your mileage may vary with different character sets if you don't encode your URLs.

http://php.net/urlencode